# Navigating/Exiting command line configuration screens from bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, configuration

I'm new to bash scripting and making a initial setup script that I can run to quickly set up a new install.

When installing ddclient

```
sudo apt-get install ddclient -y
```

it opens a command line configuration screen as below

[ddclient setup wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtJT6.png)

How do I navigate these wizards in my bash script? In a generalized case (other tools like Raspbian's `raspi-config` use a similar configuration screen), the script needs the ability in the bash script to move up, down, left, right, tab to select the `<Ok>`, enter to select item, add text etc.

How can the bash script exit these configuration screens? Then the script could easily replace the configuration file with a custom version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the environment variable DEBIAN_CLENT to "noninteractive" it will suppress this the configuration stage.

You'll get various errors through not having the configuration stage, but as you have a configuration file to put in place that shouldn't be a problem:

`sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ddclient -y`